# Can a scrollIntoView function save its position?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver

I am  having a problem with JS `scrollIntoView` getting reset after a selenium `webElement.click()` was performed. When I have used it on a custom scrollbox, it performs action correctly and then scrolls back to top after hitting `.click()`.

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='iLegenda']/ul/li[4]/i"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
Thread.sleep(500);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='iLegenda']/ul/li[4]/i")).click(); //this line resets the position of the affected scrollbar
```

An alternate solution would be force-clicking the element even though it's not displayed on screen, but I haven't found any info on that front yet...

Comment: A suggestion for your alternate solution, `$(element).trigger("click")` you would need to translate that to plain JavaScript if you can't use jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: @lasec0203 Tried it, it still resets. Am i missing something here? | 
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='iLegenda']/ul/li/ul/li[3]/i"));
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Comment: Have you tried scrolling it into view again after the click

Comment: Yup, it just resets every time a click occurs.

Comment: Well if you must have the clickable element in view for your ec2 tests then it looks like you're going to have to call scrollintoview after every click

Comment: Well that's no fun at all, but thanks for your advice. Let's see if i can get this to work.

Answer (score 0):

That's not something you can control. It's something to do with whatever the click is doing. If it were me, I would put the `.scrollIntoView()` code into a function so that it's easier to call, e.g.

```
public void scrollIntoView(WebElement e)
{
    ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", e);
}
```

and call it like

```
element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='iLegenda']/ul/li[4]/i"));
scrollIntoView(element);
```

Also, `Thread.Sleep()` is a bad practice. (You can google to learn the reasons why). You shouldn't need a wait here anyway but in case you do, it should be something like

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2);
WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).click();
```

I use Java and Selenium all the time and I've never had to scroll before clicking an element. Have you tried something simple like

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='iLegenda']/ul/li[4]/i")).click();
```

with no scroll and no wait? It should just work.

Also, if you are going to click the same element repeatedly, you should do something like

```
By locator = By.xpath("//div[@id='iLegenda']/ul/li[4]/i");
driver.findElement(locator).click();
// do something
driver.findElement(locator).click();
// ... and so on...
```

Comment: I have made a function/method/whatever it's called in java, this is just to minimize the amount of code people would have to go trough. Your "something simple" suggestion was the original code selenium IDE created while exporting to java, it worked until an element was hidden from view. Whenever that happened i got an ElementNotIneractableException and it seems like the .findElement().click() does not do anything else besides finding and clicking the found element.